# Bring header in front

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm making a website that has a menu which has to slide down from the header. The first position of the menu should be behind the header(not visible), and then it should slide down to the visible position. So, I have to bring the header in front of everything, but the problem is that the header is inside a layout, so z-index propertie is not helping here.

this is a layout

```
<body class="@ViewBag.Data">
<header class="headerStart">
    <img class="logo" src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" />
</header>
<div class="bodyW">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

and this is a second layout which has a sidebar(menu)

```
<body class="secondLayoutUserHome">   

<div class="pageWrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="sidebarToggler" />
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Settings</li>
            <li onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Index", "Home") + "'")" >Log out</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
    <div class="menuDiv">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>My reservations</li>
            <li>New reservation</li>
            <li>Pick-up places</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="userNameDiv">
        <label for="sidebarToggler">
            Fale1994
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="pageContent">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: In the code you posted here, you have the header tag right inside the body tag.
Also, use id for single types(like the header), and class if you have more tags in the same type.

Comment: OK thanks. So, the header tag shouldn't be placed in the body tag?

Comment: It should, I just don't see, why you can't use z-index with it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to put z-index=-1 for the sidebar, so it is working now. Sorry for bothering you. Thanks